# The action'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Map_map"} was not handled > by any navigator

Tags: react-native

The error appears when I click on any of the buttons from Primary.js

Error:

> The action'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Map_map"} was not handled
> by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'Map_Map?

File structure:

- app.js
- nav (folder)

  - MainContainer.js

    - Screens (folder)

      - Primary.js /trying to get from this
      - Secondary.js
      - Map_map.js  /to this

-App.js (only contains MainContainer.js

MainContainer.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

// Screens
import Primary from './Screens/Primary';
import Secondary from './Screens/Secondary';
import Map_map from './Screens/Map_map';

// Locations
const mesta = [
  {
    name: 'Praha', 
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 50.072829,
      longitude: 14.433817 
  }},
  , 
  {
    name: 'České Budějovice',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 48.975250,
      longitude: 14.479161
}},
,  
  {
    name: 'Plzeň',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 49.739296,
      longitude: 13.372455
  }},
  
  {
    name: 'Karlovy Vary', 
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 50.231656,
      longitude: 12.869226
  }},
  {
    name: 'Ústí nad Labem', 
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 50.662592,
      longitude: 14.042824
  }},
  {
    name: 'Liberec', 
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 50.764136,
      longitude: 15.047840
  }},
  {
    name: 'Hradec Králové', 
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 50.210071,
      longitude: 15.829660
  }},
  {
    name: 'Pardubice', 
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 50.032558,
      longitude: 15.773678
  }},
  {
    name: 'Jihlava', 
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 49.401642,
      longitude: 15.584001
  }},
  {
    name: 'Brno', 
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 49.190254,
      longitude: 16.614144
  }},
  {
    name: 'Olomouc', 
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 49.590450,
      longitude: 17.259280
  }},
  {
    name: 'Ostrava',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 49.820469,
      longitude: 18.269387
  }},
  {
    name: 'Zlín',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 49.224215,
      longitude: 17.668567
  }},
]

//Screen names
const lokace = "Lokace";
const mapa = "Mapa";
const mapa_det = "Mapa_det";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MainContainer() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={lokace}
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;
            let rn = route.name;

            if (rn === lokace) {
              iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline';

            } else if (rn === mapa) {
              iconName = focused ? 'map' : 'map-outline';
            }
            else if (rn === mapa_det) {
              iconName = focused ? 'locate' : 'locate-outline';
            }
            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#007aff',
          inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
          labelStyle: { paddingBottom: 10, fontSize: 10 },
          style: { padding: 10, height: 70}
        }}>

        <Tab.Screen name={lokace} children={() => <Primary towns={mesta}/>}/>
        <Tab.Screen name={mapa} children={() => <Secondary towns={mesta}/>}/>
        <Tab.Screen name={mapa_det} component={Map_map}/>

      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default MainContainer;
```

Primary.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';


export default function Primary(props, {Map_map})
{
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const map_map = "Map_map";
    return(
        <ScrollView style=
            {{ 
                flex: 1,
            }}>
            <View>
                {props.towns.map(itemz => (
                    <Text 
                    style={styles.card} 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate(map_map)}                    >
                        {itemz.name}
                    </Text>
                ))}
            </View>
            </ScrollView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card:{
        backgroundColor: "#007aff",
        borderRadius: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        margin: 5,
        padding: 10,
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    card2:{
        backgroundColor: "#FF3300",
        borderRadius: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        margin: 5,
        padding: 10,
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `name` prop to navigate instead of component name.

`<Tab.Screen name={mapa_det} component={Map_map}/>`

So, it should be:

`navigation.navigate("Mapa_det")`